# Is "disclude" a word and what authority says a word is a word or isn't?

Tags: meaning, verbs, is-it-a-word

So far this is what I found from Wiktionary and Merriam-Webster except the latter doesn't have *disclude*.

- *Exclude* — To keep something out.
  From Latin *excludere*, from *ex-*, “out”, + variant form of the verb *claudere*, “to close”.
- *Preclude* — To prevent something from happening.
  From Latin *praeclūdere*, “to shut up”, from *prae-* + *claudere*, “to close”.
- *Disclude* — To shut apart.
  Latin *discludere*, “to shut apart”.

Comment: There's a vital part of what Wiktionary has to say about 'disclude' that you seem not to have discovered or thought relevant: Verb
**disclude** ...
(nonstandard) To disclose, make known.
(nonstandard) To exclude, not include; to remove from inclusion. Inclusion in the OED without such a tag as 'slang' or 'nonstandard' would usually be considered as the best authority for acceptability. An Ngram or Google search might point towards idiomaticity.

Comment: Standard or not, I do wonder why so many people keep asking for an authority to decide things for them (and what the question "Is it a word?" is even supposed to mean). If a word is used and understood, then it is a word. If *disclude* ["may be uttered in isolation with semantic or pragmatic content (with literal or practical meaning)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word), then it is a word.

Comment: @RegDwight: Other definitions for **word** emphasise the 'must be communicated to / understood by others' aspect better: eg AHD: 
1. A sound or a combination of sounds, or its representation in writing or printing, that symbolizes and communicates a meaning. >> This means that not every string should be considered to be a word. We now approach neologisms, nonce-words, pseudowords; argots;; deaf audiences ... and the age-old **what authority says a word is a word or isn't?**

Comment: @RegDwight Obvious when you think about it, innit!

Comment: I have no problem with one's forming words with well-known affixes. Dis this, dis that. This ful, that ful. No problem, understood.

Comment: @Talia Ford  Thankfully, the OED compilers (and those of other reputable dictionaries) take a rather less subjective view.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it's a misspelling of "exclude", because I've only ever seen a non-native speaker invent that word and use it. Haven't once seen a native speaker use it. In fact, it's an easy way to spot a non-native speaker.

Comment: If we interclude the countercluded paraclusions, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the second question :

1- In countries like the English-speaking ones, there is no overall regulation ; a word becomes part of the language if it is used and generally understood, especially when forged by a recognized writer, who gives him some right to live (about one third of the words, in Shakespeare, were invented by him, and many are still in use).

2- In countries like the French-speaking ones, there is an Academy supposed to rule both vocabulary and syntax. In fact their works are very slow (they study every word one by one in alphabetic order, returning to the beginning takes 26 years ! - what about new words appearing just too late ?), and the members are elected more for political motives than real competence - some have hardly written anything). Before the institution by Richelieu (who thought he was himself a distinguished linguist bus was deeply mistaken), the situation was sounder, the language was living and burgeoning, with authors like Rabelais for instance.
Now, *de facto*, French is ruled by two commercial publishers : Larousse and Robert ; each year, they allow new words or suppress obsolete ones, just following the use, without any real criterion - except to publish a new, updated, reference book you must buy.

Comment: There is no _overall_ regulation. Teachers still mark some strings wrong, relying, it is to be hoped, on OED to inform their decisions. Editors still fire writers they feel will not be publicly accepted / understood. People get downvoted on certain websites ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree, edited.

Comment: "about one third of the words, in Shakespeare, were invented by him" ... Perhaps.  Or maybe some of these words  were already known, but Shakespeare was the first to write them in a document that comes down to the present.

Comment: L'Académie française doesn't actually control the French language, though.  They can convince some people not to say *email*, but they can't make something "not a word", and people are free to ignore them in any case.

Comment: As regards your remarkable assertion that one-third of Shakespeare's words were invented by him, on which @GEdgar also comments, [this is Marc Antony's funeral speech from *Julius Caesar*](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/56968/speech-friends-romans-countrymen-lend-me-your-ears). It contains 1,482 words. Please would you tell me which were invented by Shakespeare, because I cannot find one that would seem to have been. If your one-third rule were applied equally across all of WS's writings, 494 of them would have been.

Answer (score 2):

"**Exclude**" is keeping the thing outside of the castle walls (wherein you are).

"**Disclude**", properly, is a setting-apart – e.g., the guy in the jail cell.

My feeling is that "**Disclose**" is sufficient for the purpose of meaning "revealing/stating of information" (and that "**Divulge**" is distinct in that it connotes the revealing of information sensitive in nature).

Using "**Disclude**" to mean "**Disclose**" is as clumsy as putting lipstick on a cat.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, the proper query is not "Is it a word", but rather "is this term in use widely enough that there seems to be a common meaning" and, if so, another question: "What is the etymology of this word?".

As thinking beings, we are always creating new words to express either something old in our civilization or something new. This is the way I look at it. Now, it may be that a word that seems new is not really novel but is being used in a novel way, or even so that it has a different or opposite meaning to its traditional meaning. "Cool" comes to mind. That's where an understanding of the etymology comes in handy.

So these are my thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is not a discussion forum, but a [site where questions are asked and answered](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour). "You have asked the wrong question" is very rarely a valid answer. However, perhaps you could demonstrate using the etymology to say whether *disclude* is a word. Just [edit] to take out your last sentence and add the answer to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/416785)