# Is there a difference between disclude vs exclude?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, transatlantic-differences

I say `exclude` if I want to prevent inclusion in the first place.

I say `disclude` if I want to express that I remove something that was already previously included (as in its [`remove from inclusion`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disclude) meaning in *wiktionary*).

Is this usage correct?

What is the tradition of using these words in the English-speaking world?

**update**: I ask for the *tradition* precisely because this word is [listed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disclude) as "nonstandard", but without specifics (like usage history).

**update**: `disclude` differs from `discard` in that something removed from an inclusion can still be used for another purpose. Example by David Pugh: *"Following my disclusion from the group, I went off by myself and had a wonderful time"*.

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary?

Comment: Is *disclude* a word?

Comment: *Disclude* is not in use in Standard PDE. *OED 1* gives a 15th century use in the sense *disclose*, and 17th-century uses of *disclusion* to mean *emission* (of light).

Comment: @naxa are you sure you did not meant "discard" instead of "disclude" ?

Comment: @Robusto yes, at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disclude . It says `2. (non-standard)` ... `to remove from inclusion.`

Comment: @P.Obertelli no I am not. however [wiktionary lists](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disclude) this word as 'non-standard' with the meaning of `remove from inclusion`. But part of the question is whether, or rather to what extent is `disclude` a word, that's why I ask for the "*tradition*".

Comment: close voters: if your reason is that disclude should not be a word, maybe you migrate the question to ell? but also see my wiktionary ref linked.

Comment: Well I'm 62, an English NS, somewhat of a bookworm and yet I've never seen this word. That should tell you something about how standard it isn't.

Comment: I did not downvote, but perhaps some did because (as Robusto noted) there was no mention of what a dictionary says.

Comment: There is already an answer to this question [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129015/is-disclude-a-word-and-what-authority-says-a-word-is-a-word-or-isnt)

Comment: @Mynamite I saw that but its accepted answer only addresses the 'second question', specifically `what authority says a word is a word or isn't?` - and that says exactly nothing about the tradition or history behind the [nonstandard] usage of `disclude`.

Comment: @StoneyB that is really interesting. However the sense that interests me the most is `remove from inclusion`, from the tradition/history point of view.

Comment: I don't know if you're particularly interested in finding standard-English synonyms for the word "disclude" that you present, but it seems to me that   in most contexts, "remove from inclusion" is redundant and the single word "remove" conveys the concept just as well. In strictly social contexts, "remove" might not work and a word like "ostracize", "reject", or one of its synonyms might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference: "exclude" is a standard English word; "disclude" is a nonstandard English word.

**added**
Actually, "disclude" is a word used in dentistry...

> To cause (opposing teeth) to fail to meet when the jaws are closed. Also intr.: (of opposing teeth) to fail to meet.

Other than the dental meaning, the Oxford English Dictionary says of "disclude": *Somewhat rare and nonstandard since 18th cent.*

Ngram finds about 50,000 uses of "exclude" for each one use of "disclude".   I guess that qualifies it as *rare*.

Comment: I see, but what does that exactly mean? Could you elaborate on the "*tradition*" part? because that's why I've asked that.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant  *discard* vs *exclude*, then you're partially right.

Discard means only excluding something which was already present (Collins)

> (transitive) to get rid of as useless or undesirable (cards)
>
> to throw out (a card or cards) from one's hand

whereas *exclude* means first to bar from entering,

> to keep out; prevent from entering
>
> to reject or not consider; leave out

but by derivation also can be used in the sense of ejecting something already there.

> to expel forcibly; eject
>
> to debar from school, either temporarily or permanently, as a form of
> punishment

If you really meant "disclude" then I'm lost.

Comment: thanks very much for the suggestion! I'm not yet sure: Discard seems to imply that the thing is not used for any other purpose. If you remove something from an inclusion that seems to let you use it for other purposes still.

Comment: @Naxa. For that reason it sounds a useful word. "Following my disclusion from the group, I went off by myself and had a wonderful time". In your honour I might start using it myself. Although it's non-standard, it's transparent enough, and so people will just have to get used to it.

Comment: nice sentence! I updated the question with it. I hope it's okay!

Answer (score 0):

The 'ex' prefix suggests a positional value (or version), either in or out a certain object. The 'dis' prefix implies negation, absent of a positional value. Similarly, there are 'un', 'de' and 'ab'.

In terms of negation:

- 'Un' is commonly used to indicate state.
- 'De' is commonly used to indicate recovery to a previous state.
- 'Ab' is commonly used to indicate detachment, with emphasis on range.